# X11 session environment

Tags: linux, x11

I want to run specific command in X11 session automatically, as soon as I take the session.

e.g. If I do

```
Xephyr :2 -once -query <ip_address>
```

then post successful authentication, a command e.g. `export ABCD=small` need to get executed automatically.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Your line of code starts an X server, not an X session (which consists of a bunch of X clients). Furthermore, `export ABCD=small` is not a command, but a shell snippet, which only has effect in the shell that runs it and the subprocesses that this shell starts. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Though it is a shell snippet, but that was given for example.